# Variáveis com BigDecimal

Tags: java

Estou tentando adicionar um valor em uma variável do tipo BigDecimal, porém independente do cálculo ela resulta em 0.

Código exemplo:

---

```
    BigDecimal valorTotal = new BigDecimal(0);

    public void adicionarVenda(int idProduto, int quantidade) {
         BigDecimal newQtd = new BigDecimal(quantidade);
         BigDecimal newQtd2 = newQtd.multiply(preco);
         valorTotal.add(newQtd2);
         System.out.println(valorTotal);
    }
```

Comment: Qual o valor de `preco` que você usou?

Comment: O preço está em BigDecimal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você não pode modificar o valor `BigDecimal`, ele é imutável. Por isso, você deve criar um novo `BigDecimal` para armazenar o resultado, que deve ser o objetivo de sua variável `valorTotal`.

**Exemplo:**
Assumindo que `preco` é 10 e que `quantidade` também é 10:

```
BigDecimal preco = new BigDecimal(10);
```

E modificando seu método para:

```
      BigDecimal newQtd = new BigDecimal(quantidade);
      BigDecimal newQtd2 = newQtd.multiply(preco);

      valorTotal = valorTotal.add(newQtd2); // <<

      System.out.println(valorTotal.toString());
```

O resultado é 100.
Versão no ideone: [link](http://ideone.com/LlZcCQ).

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece porque o método [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) **somente retorna** um BigDecimal.

Para corrigir, basta que você atribua a soma ao valor total:

```
valorTotal = valorTotal.Add(newQtd2);
```